# filter NSArray by properties in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of objects (Person) with type described as follow:

```
@inteface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *age;

@end
```

Is there any fast way to convert the list of Person to list of names and list of ages ?

Or better question is how to filter an array by a property of its objects?

```
NSArray <Person*> *list = ; //- initiate a list of people here...
NSArray <NSString*> *names;
NSArray <NSNumber*> *ages;
```

Comment: Are you looking to map the list of Person objects to a list of names (or age) or are you looking to filter the list of Person objects by their names (or age)? They're two different things. Also, what have you tried so far? There are many ways you could do this (depending on what you're trying to do).

Comment: I prefer to have a short way to do like the filter method in Swift language.

Comment: `valueForKeyPath:`? But why do you want to "desynchronize" them? `names = [list valueForKeyPath:@"names"]; ages = [list valueForKeyPath:"ages"];`

Comment: @Larme: sometimes, it's needed to fill the UI stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    NSMutableArray *personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Person *p1 = [[Person alloc] init];
    p1.name = @"sam";
    p1.age = @24;
    Person *p2 = [[Person alloc] init];
    p2.name = @"sangram";
    p2.age = @25;

    [personArray addObject:p1];
    [personArray addObject:p2];

    NSArray *arrName = [personArray valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSArray *arrAge = [personArray valueForKey:@"age"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `valueForKey`:

```
NSArray *names = [persons valueForKey:@"name"];
NSArray *ages = [persons valueForKey:@"age"];
```